# Python equivalent of ruby's __method__?

Tags: python, ruby

I want to be able to do this:

```
def asdf():
  print __method__
"asdf"
```

Thanks,
Noah

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the traceback module:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import traceback
def asdf():
    (filename,line_number,function_name,text)=traceback.extract_stack()[-1]
    print function_name
asdf()
```

Answer (score 8):

You need to specify your usecase in order for us to give you a better answer.
Why do you want to do this?

You can get a string with the name of a function by using `__name__`:

```
def asdf():
    print asdf.__name__
"asdf"
```

But, what would be the point? You might aswell just print the name directly in that case.

What would happen in this case?

```
def asdf():
    print __method__

foo = asdf
foo()
```

Print `"foo"` or `"asdf"`?